# Pthread conditional sleep?

Tags: multithreading, pthreads, conditional-statements, sleep

I am trying to find an easy way to sleep or stop executing, and wake another (so not the calling ) thread in C.
It shoud work like this:

```
main()
{
    int msg = 0;
    ptread_t t;
    pthread_create(&t, NULL, work, NULL)
    while(1)
    {
        msg = recieve_msg();
        switch(msg)
        case 1:
             //sleep_pthread(t);
             break;
        case 2:
             //wake_pthread(t);
             break;
        default:
             break;
    }
}

void work()
{ //do whatever it needs to
}
```

recieve_msg() waits for a user action so I don't know how much time i have to stop the thread from execution.
Where I need help is which functions should i use for those **sleep_pthread(t);** and **wake_pthread(t);** parts.

Answer (score 1):

From what you are saying "find an easy way to sleep or stop executing, and wake another (so not the calling ) thread in C" - your requirement seems to suggest you need simple pthread_cond_wait or pthread_cond_timedwait to satisfy your needs. By using them you are forcing them to go into sleep state till condition is not satisfied or timer expires.

Below is sample code

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define WAIT_TIME_SECONDS  15
typedef struct mystruct_tag
{
    pthread_mutex_t  mutex;
    pthread_cond_t   cond;
    int              value;
} mystruct_t;

mystruct_t data = {PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER, PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER, 0};

/* 
 * thread start routine. It will set the main thread's predicate and 
 * signal the condition variable
 */

 void *wait_thread (void *arg)
 {
     int status;
     long sleep_time = (long)arg;

     status = pthread_mutex_lock(&data.mutex);
     if (status != 0)
     {
         printf(" failed \n");
     }
     sleep(sleep_time);
     data.value = 1;  /*set predicate */
     status = pthread_cond_signal (&data.cond);

     if (status != 0)
     {
         printf(" failed at condition \n");
     }

     status = pthread_mutex_unlock (&data.mutex);

     return NULL;
 }

 int main (void)
 {
     int status;
     pthread_t wait_thread_id;
     struct timespec timeout;
     struct timeval    tp;

     pthread_create(&wait_thread_id, NULL, wait_thread, (void *)50);

     timeout.tv_sec  = tp.tv_sec;
     timeout.tv_nsec = 0;
     timeout.tv_sec += WAIT_TIME_SECONDS;

     pthread_mutex_lock(&data.mutex);

     while(data.value == 0)
     {
         pthread_cond_timedwait (&data.cond, &data.mutex, &timeout); /*can use cond_wait too instead of timedwait*/
     }     
     status = pthread_mutex_unlock(&data.mutex);

     return 0;
 }
```

Comment: If I get this right, in this example the thread locks the mutex and the main is forced to wait the thread to unlock it.
So it waits at a certain execution point, however what I need is "stop that 't' thread from execution" type of thing, no metter where it's execution point is.

In this example of yours its like stop the execution between **sleep(sleep_time);** and **data.value = 1;**

Comment: In other words this seems to be a synchronous wait and i should have an asynchronous solution

Comment: The basic concept is  "status = pthread_cond_signal (&data.cond);" --> signals the intended thread to come out of sleep and start executing.  The thread you want to have waiting should be made to wait with pthread_cond_timedwait (&data.cond, &data.mutex, &timeout); or pthread_cond_wait (&data.cond, &data.mutex); But keep in mind to loop the wait part with a while loop to prevent from spurious wake up conditions

Answer (score 0):

You can not sleep nor wake the thread from the outside. Moreover, any design which requires this functionality is broken. Why do you need to just turn the thread to sleep? What you need is a proper synchronization points betyween threads, so that thread will simply wait when there is no work for it to be done.

Comment: I'd consider this "*any design which requires this functionality is broken*" too harsh.

Comment: @alk, well, think about it. You've launched the thread because it needs to do something, right? Now, it has either thread work queue, or it was just ad-hoc launched. For threads with work queue, empty queue should indicate there is no work and you need to pause, and ad-hoc will end once all is done. In both cases, why on earth do you want to pause a thread which has something to do?

Comment: The thread also has an infinite cycle in it, and 1 cycle takes about 5  seconds to finish. Yet, when the request comes I should immediately stop the thread, no metter where the execution point of the thread is. That is why i need to "suspend" and "continue" the thread from the outside.

Comment: @AndrásHetényi - just like I said, your design is broken.